# printf() giving identical output on x86-64 platforms even when arguments are swapped

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%lf %ld\n", 1234.0, 5678L);
    printf("%lf %ld\n", 5678L, 1234.0);
}
```

Both calls to `printf` prints the same text `1234.000000 5678`, which doesn't very well match up with the code on the second call (should probably have been `5678.0000 1234`).

I'm on Linux 4.x on a x86-64 processor, but I am not able to reproduce this on x86 (32-bit). I suppose it's reproducible on any Linux system on amd64 architecture.

Why does swapped arguments give the same output for `printf`, and why is it specific to x86-64?

Comment: The second line invokes undefined behaviour; anything can happen and it is OK.  Somewhat to my surprise, I am able to reproduce the problem, using GCC 8.3.0 on a RHEL 5 platform.

Comment: actually if you compile with -m32 you get different output..
1234.000000 5678.....
0.000000 1083394048

Comment: @user3386109 That duplicate doesn't answer anything.

Comment: It answers your question. If the format you provide to `printf` doesn't match the arguments, the result is undefined behavior. End of story. There's nothing more to say.

Comment: In this specific case, the undefined behavior works out the way it does due to the x86_64 ABI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is because it's how the System V ABI x86-64 defines how arguments should be passed.

According to [PDF](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) page 22, the first 6 integer arguments are passed on %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, %r9, and the first 8 floating-point arguments are passed from %xmm0 to %xmm7. However, **there's no specific order between integers and floats**. Therefore, the following two functions, despite being defined differently, behave the same.

```
int f1(int i1, int i2, int i3, double d1, double d2, double d3);
int f2(double d1, double d2, int i1, int i2, double d3, int i3);
```

As compiled following the Syetem V x86-64 ABI, both functions will receive i1, i2 and i3 in registers %rdi, %rsi and %rdx, and d1, d2 and d3 in registers %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm2.

Variadic arguments are no exception. Up to 6 integers and up to 8 floats are passed via registers, and the rest are passed on stack.

Talking about this specific code, by inspecting the assembly code generated by `gcc -O0 -S`, I verified the above statements: The integer 5678 is sent to printf via %rsi, and the (double-precision) floating-point value 1234.0 is sent to printf via %xmm0. In both cases, %eax is set to 1, indicating there's one floating-point argument available.

Oh yeah where's %rdi? Actually, the formatting string is the first argument, so a pointer to the string is passed via %rdi.

**printf doesn't know if the integer is before the float or the other way**, it only knows it has one integer argument (after the formatting string) and one floating-point argument (reading %al). This is exactly why the two lines produce identical output.

*TODO: someone put a Godbolt link here?*